# Delegates and Predicate enquiry

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I'm learning about lambdas and I'm trying to understand why, while having EmployeeFilterAge class like so:

```
public class EmployeeFilterAge
{
    int _age;
    public EmployeeFilterAge(int age)
    {
        _age = age;
    }
    public bool OlderThan(Employee employee)
    {
        return employee._age > _age;
    }
}
```

when I'm trying to do this:

```
var filterByAge = new EmployeeFilterAge(29);
var del = new AgeExclusion(filterByAge.OlderThan);
```

I get an error saying "no overload method ... matches delegate ...", while delegate looks like that:

```
public delegate bool AgeExclusion(object person);
```

Is this because its a predicate?

Comment: For reference, [Predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate says that the parameter can be of any type.  When someone invokes the method they can pass in a Lion, a Tiger, a Bear (Oh My!!!), or whatever else they want, and your method needs to be able to handle it.

You're trying to assign a method that can only ever accept an `Employee`, and that isn't allowed to accept any other type as an argument, so obviously it's not a valid method to assign to a variable of that delegate type.

Now if the types were reversed, it would be fine.  If the delegate said that it could accept a method that takes only an `Employee` as an argument, then you could give it a method that is able to take *anything* as an argument, because after all, all of the employees that it will pass it would be valid arguments for a method that can accept *anything*.  The technical term for this is contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a method group that takes an `Employee` for a delegate that takes an `object`. This is not allowed because the user of the delegate is allowed to pass an `object`, while the delegate expects an `Employee`.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
AgeExclusion del = e => filterByAge.OlderThan((Employee)e);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/v2KcGm)